# Favorite taxonomy archive page?

Tags: users

I have a website with multiple Genre's as custom taxonomies.

I would like to allow users to like or favorite taxonomy archive pages, but I can't seem to figure out any way to do this.

Lots of plugins/code snippets to favourite posts and pages, but nothing that would allow me to favourite a tag_id.

I have ACF and I'm open to anything custom that might get the job done, any suggestions?

Comment: Can you share some of the things you've tried? Note that plugin recommendations are off topic here, and you'll need to be able to mark an answer as the factually correct answer, not just the reply you like most